# Refreshing android Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to reload the list view when the data has changed. But its not working.Here is the code I am using

```
localPits.clear();//
this.adapter.clear();
//Fetch new data and update the list
this.localPits.addAll(pl);
this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
this.lst_Pits.invalidate();
```

Each time I call this portion of code existing values are successfully removed. But new values are not loaded in the list view.

How can I do this in android?
Thanks

Comment: does .getView() of Adapter gets called (if it's your custom implementation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not terribly clear, but I suspect the new values aren't being loaded because you're clearing the adapter without updating it.

Your 2nd line: `this.adapter.clear();`

You need to update and add the adapter before you call `invalidate()`. Or, at least, that's as far as I can gather.

Answer (score 0):

`this.adapter.clear();` should not be needed. It must reset the links between `adapter` and `localPits`.

If you need to keep this, update list adapter `localPits.setAdapter(adapter);`. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I dont clear the list view remans same. Also I tried to update adapter as you mentioned but no success.

Comment: `adapter` is a ListAdapter or a custom class ?

Comment: Here's a example of working [custom adapter class](https://github.com/Neamar/OmnilogieAndroid/blob/master/src/fr/omnilogie/app/ArticleObjectAdapter.java). Hope it can help you.

Comment: [Alehar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1137335/alehar) is right, check your `CustomAdapter.getView()`.